# DropboxAPI putFile Progress value returned is invalid

Tags: android, file-upload, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am Integrating Dropbox sdk in my sample application. Everything works perfectly except showing upload progress on screen. I am using DropboxAPI [putFile](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#putFile(java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream,%20long,%20java.lang.String,%20com.dropbox.client2.ProgressListener)) API to file on Dropbox.This API provides ProgressListener which publish progress in onProgress method. The issue I am getting over here is it seems that onProgress doesnt returns the correct values. for e.g below are the logs which I am seeing. It just stops after showing last log and file is uploaded successfully. I am trying to find a callback where It would let me know that file upload is complete.

```
04-20 09:51:30.041  27244-27452/google.dropboxfilesample I/vipul﹕ 2048<===>2330600
04-20 09:51:31.801  27244-27452/google.dropboxfilesample I/vipul﹕ 327680<===>2330600
04-20 09:51:32.851  27244-27452/google.dropboxfilesample I/vipul﹕ 473088<===>2330600
04-20 09:51:33.851  27244-27452/google.dropboxfilesample I/vipul﹕ 604160<===>2330600
04-20 09:51:34.561  27244-27452/google.dropboxfilesample I/vipul﹕ 753664<===>2330600
04-20 09:51:35.211  27244-27452/google.dropboxfilesample I/vipul﹕ 868352<===>2330600
04-20 09:51:35.881  27244-27452/google.dropboxfilesample I/vipul﹕ 1011712<===>2330600
04-20 09:51:36.381  27244-27452/google.dropboxfilesample I/vipul﹕ 1277952<===>2330600
04-20 09:51:36.911  27244-27452/google.dropboxfilesample I/vipul﹕ 1441792<===>2330600
04-20 09:51:37.701  27244-27452/google.dropboxfilesample I/vipul﹕ 1761280<===>2330600
04-20 09:51:38.201  27244-27452/google.dropboxfilesample I/vipul﹕ 2201600<===>2330600


private void uploadFile() throws FileNotFoundException, DropboxException {
    final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "sample.mp3");
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(progressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progressDialog.setMax((int) file.length());
    progressDialog.show();
    new Thread() {
      @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                final DropboxAPI.Entry response = mDBApi.putFile("/sample.mp3", inputStream,
                    file.length(), null, new ProgressListener() {@
                        Override
                        public void onProgress(final long bytes, final long total) {
                            Log.d("vipul", bytes + "<===>" + total);
                        }
                    });
                Log.d("vipul", "The uploaded file's rev is: " + response.rev);
            } catch (DropboxException dropboxException) {
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                dropboxException.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

It would be great if someone could point me to correct direction.
Thanks

Comment: Reading through the API docs seems to imply that only intermediate progress is reported to `onProgress`, and that completion of the upload is signaled by `putFile()` returning. Is that `uploaded file's rev...` log entry not showing? Is it possible that log entry could be missing due the the thread exit interacting with your logging mechanism?

Comment: @AndrewJanke You are absolutely correct completion of the upload is signaled by putFile() returning. But Since I am showing horizontal % progress bar . I want that dialog should dismiss after progress is reached 100% . currently it just reaches 2201600<===>2330600  (it should be 2330600<===>2330600) and dialog is dismissed. so ultimately I am not seeing 100% progress.

Comment: I believe what Andrew's saying (which sounds correct) is that you're not guaranteed to get a progress callback for 100% (2330600<===>2330600 in this case). If you need to show the progress bar as 100% done, you'll need to do so manually once the `putFile` method returns, indicating the upload is complete.

Comment: @Greg Yup I would take same path.

Comment: @AndrewJanke Can you please post that comment as an answer so I can accept your answer. Thanks :)